# Starting Dolphin with shortcut Meta+E

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I'm used to open a file manager with the shortcut meta+e from Windows.

Now I would like to have the same behavior under Plasma 5.

I've edited the shortcut here:

[image]

But when I use the shortcut nothing happens.

I also tried another shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+E but this won't work either.

How to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: How did you set that? Did you type `Win+E` or did you manually enter "Meta"? Meta is usually Alt, not Win.

Comment: I pressed Win and this results in Meta. But using other shortcuts like Crtl+Alt+E doesn't work either...

Comment: Hang on, what's that dialog from? You don't seem to have set any action for the shortcut and the dialog talks about some kind of "applet". It looks like you're in the wrong place. There should be a shortcut and an action associated with tat shortcut. You seem to be in the task manager's settings, not the system keyboard shortcuts'.

Comment: Yes you are right. No I see that this is the setting or the task bar. Where can I define a shortcut that starts dolphin?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't been a KDE user for more than a decade. Such things are usually located in "keyboard settings" => "shortcuts".

Comment: I found a place what seems to be 'more right'. But it still won't work.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the right place. First try with Ctrl+E or similar, since the win key is sometimes problematic. Also, make sure you log out and log back in again, just in case that is needed to refresh the list of shortcuts.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Alt+E logged out and back in but it still does not work :(

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and include all these details from the comments. Comments can be deleted with no warning and are much harder to read.

Comment: I have edited the original post...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**KDE application launcher shortcuts**

The KDE shortcuts can be added from the KDE menu editor - online: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html

> KMenuEdit allows editing the menu of KDE application launchers.
>
> KMenuEdit can be started either by right mouse button clicking the
>   application launcher button on the panel and choosing Edit
>   Applications..., or by typing kmenuedit in the KRunner line.

To add Dolphin launch shortcut key: KDE Menueditor > System > Dolphin > Advanced tab > Current shortcut key

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In Kubuntu 18.04, it is very simple. Open "System Settings" in the main menu (click on Kubuntu icon on the bottom left to find this option in the "Favorites" section) then click on "Shortcuts" on the left menu of the System Settings window.

Inside the "Shortcuts" main window, select "Custom Shortcuts" and then click on the "Edit" button at the bottom of the middle left tab section. Select "New/Global Shortcut/CommandURL". By doing this, you will create a new custom command for the keyboard that will show under all the other commands that are already created. You can rename the new command by double-clicking on the new command name. Good practice keeping things tidy but it is up to you.

Now the key binding part. Select the newly created command and on the main window, click on the "Action" tab. There will be only one Command/URL field. In that field you simply type "dolphin" (without quotes). Next you click on the "Trigger" tab located besides the "Action" tab on the top of the window and then click on the button to the right of the word "Shortcut:", the button will change its name to "Input". Now it is the time to set the combination that you want on your keyboard. In this case, just hit Meta+E (like in windows to open win explorer, yack..) on the keyboard to bind the key combo to the new command and that's it.

Now you have your personal shortcut to open dolphin through the keyboard.